# Dynamic Text field grow in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have fields in Crystal reports as:

*In Report Header* values of my **parameters** are shown as:

```
Country :(Allows no multiple values)
Subjects :(Allows multiple values)
Hobbies :(Allows multiple values)
Date of Birth :(Allows no multiple values)
```

Here all above are parameters.

Detail section is based on the parameters selected.

When Subjects and Hobbies values are small in length(say Physics,Chemistry for Subjects and Singing,Dancing for Hobbies) than it is ok in report header, as it will come in a row.

When Subjects and Hobbies values are very lengthy (say for Subjects Physics,Chemistry,Maths,English,Biology,Pharmacy,xxx,gggggggggggg,hhhhhhhhhhhh,ttttttttt,gggggggggggg,hhhhhhhhhh,jjjjjjjj,rthrhrjtjrjryyyjty)

Then, here the values of Subjects will Overlay with the values of Hobbies(As it will come in more than 2 rows).How to handle it so that, when multiple values grow as lengthy as possible, then Subjects and Hobbies will be automatically get separated(dynamically) as below:

**Country** : India

**Subjects**:Physics,Chemistry,Maths,English,Biology,Pharmacy,xxx,gggggggggggg,hhhhhhhhhhhh,
         ttttttttt,gggggggggggg,hhhhhhhhhh,jjjjjjjj,rthrhrjtjrjryyyjty

**Hobbies** :Singing,Dancing,Painting,Travelling,Swimming,Reading,Writing,Sleeping,Jumping,
          Dancing,Singing Melody Songs,Dancing Hiphops

**Date of Birth** :11/12/2012

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a new section for each vertical separated field. This way the section will grow with the field, pushing the following section/field down.